# Highcharts (ng2-highcharts) gauge in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic3

I want to use highchart's gauges in my Ionic App.

I've installed highcharts following the steps shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196806/1837599
and here https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts/wiki/Ionic-usage

It worked for the given example, but when I try to use a gauge chart, I get the error "Error: Highcharts error #17".

After some research, I found that I need to include highcharts-more.js before loading the gauge.

- Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36584536/1837599
- Ref: https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/issues/254

I tried to include:

```
<script src="../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

at index.html but it did not work.

How should I include the libraries at IONIC? Or even before that, is it really what I need to do?

> - ionic version: 3.20.0
> - npm version: 5.6.0
> - "highcharts": "^6.0.7",
> - "ng2-highcharts": "^1.1.2",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check official [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts)  for more details

Steps

1>Install from npm

npm install --save highcharts

2> In home.ts import highcharts and highcharts-more.js

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import More from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
More(Highcharts);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-highcharts-gauge?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts) demo

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Could not be more simple. It still have some issue with types. For some reason it does not recognize the background attribute of the pane configuration. But it is good enough.